# Query to find "friends of friends" SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having some problems with sql...

I have a table with 3 columns: *user_id, name, friend_id*;

and I need to find for each user_id the friends of his friends, but **not** the friends! The result schema should be *user_id* | *suggested_user_id*

I've already searched for answers but the problem is that users and friends are in the same table! I'm not very good with postgresql, so excuse me if I'm not clear or it's easy, but I really need a help!

Thank you very much

Comment: Both MySQL and Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved... Also, I'd suggest a user table (userid and name), and a separate friendship table.

Comment: ok thank you for the suggestion; I can't alter the table, this is why I need help! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
select DISTINCT
    u1.user_id as user_id,u3.user_id as suggested_user_id
    from
    users as u1 
    inner join users as u2 on u1.user_id=u2.friend_id
    inner join users as u3 on u2.user_id=u3.friend_id
where u1.user_id<>u3.user_id
```

Comment: You'll also need to check that `u3.user_id` is not a direct friend of `u1` (in the case `u1` and `u2` both share a 'direct' friend).

Comment: ok thank you, another mini-question: how can I avoid duplicates? because in the results I see user1 with many times the same suggested friend...

Comment: added DISTINCT keyword to address dupes.  We'll get there eventually... :)

Comment: wow, I feel so stupid now, thank you very much, I'm sorry but my reputation doesn't allow me to Vote Up the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join, i.e. join the table with itself:

```
select t1.user_id, t1.name, t2.friend_id as suggested_user_id
from usertable t1
  join usertable t2 on t1.friend_id = t2.user_id
```

Perhaps you want to add

```
 where t1.user_id <> t2.friend_id
```

To avoid listing a user as friend to himself.